# $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + b, \mathrm{lcm}[a,b])$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Show that if $a$, $b$ are positive integers, then we have:
$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + b, \mathrm{lcm}[a,b])$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below are a few proofs, starting with two from my [sci.math post on 2001/11/10](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.math.undergrad/msg/a687e26e7db0396d)

First, recalling that  [gcd distributes over lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242) we obtain

$$(a\!+\!b,[a,b])\, =\, [(a\!+\!b,a),(a\!+\!b,b)]\, =\, [(b,a),(a,b)]\, =\, (a,b)$$

---

Or, cancelling $\,(a,b)\,$ [homo reduces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3658798/242) to case $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ so $\,ab = [a,b],\ $ so by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/875914/242)

$$\begin{eqnarray}(a\!+\!b,\color{#c00}a) = (b,a)= 1\\ (a\!+\!b,\color{#c00}b)=(a,b)=1\end{eqnarray}\ \Rightarrow\ 1 = (a\!+\!b,\color{#c00}{ab}) = (a\!+\!b,[a,b])$$

---

For variety here is yet another using $\rm\ (a,b)\  [a,b]\ =\ \color{#c00}{ab}\ \ $ and [basic gcd laws:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242)

$\rm\quad (a,b)\ (a\!+\!b,\, [a,b])\, =\, (aa\!+\!ab,\, ab\!+\!bb,\, \color{#c00}{ab})\ =\ (aa,\,bb,\,ab)\, =\, (a,b)^2$

---

By the way, recall that the key identity in the second proof arose the other day in our discussion of [Stieltjes $\rm\ 4\:n+3\ $ generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21333/help-understand-the-proof-of-infinitely-many-prime-of-the-form-ax-b/21338#21338) of Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes. Here's a slicker proof:

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ (a\!+\!b,\,ab) = 1 \iff (a,b) = 1$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ \ (\color{#90f}a,b)^2 \color{#C00}{\large\subseteq} (a\!+\!b,\,ab) \color{#0a0}{\large \subseteq} (a,b)\ \ $ since, $ $ e.g. $\rm\ \ \color{#90f}{a^2} = a(a\!+\!b)-ab\color{#c00}{\large \in} (a\!+\!b,\,ab)$.

$\rm\ 1\in (a\!+\!b,\, ab) \color{#0a0}{\large\subseteq}(a,b)\Rightarrow 1\in (a,b).\:$ Conversely $\rm\ 1 \in (a,b) \Rightarrow 1 \in (a,b)^2\color{#c00}{\large\color{#c00}\subseteq} (a\!+\!b,\,ab)$

Answer (score 7):

Another Dubuquesque attempt; for legibility, write $d=\gcd(a,b)$:
\begin{align*}
\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b), ab\Bigr) &= \gcd\Bigl(d(a+b), ab, ab\Bigr)\\
&=\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b),\ ab-a(a+b),\ ab-b(a+b)\Bigr)\\
&=\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b),\ a^2,\ b^2\Bigr)\\
&=\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b),\ \gcd(a^2,b^2)\Bigr)\\
&=\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b),\ \gcd(a,b)^2\Bigr)\\
&=\gcd\Bigl(d(a+b),\ d^2\Bigr)\\
&= d\gcd\Bigl(a+b,d\Bigr)\\
&= d\gcd\Bigl(a+b,\gcd(a,b)\Bigr)\\
&= d\gcd(a,b)\\
&= \gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,b).
\end{align*}

(Second line uses the fact that $a(a+b)$ and $b(a+b)$ are both multiples of $d(a+b)$).

Now divide through by $\gcd(a,b)$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Bill must be feeling at least some pride; after so many years of following up in `sci.math` with "SIMPLER...", I've *finally* started looking for arguments along these lines, even if they aren't the best one available just yet.

Comment: Thanks, you're too kind. Although I haven't checked all the details, I think the above derivation is -  at the  core - closely related to the one in my post employing the GCD*LCM law. It should prove illuminating to compare the two.

Comment: @Bill: If I'm not mistaken, it's the one you labeled "for variety"; at least, that's the identity I was trying to establish when this computation worked.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps overkill, but if you accept the 'distribution law' $(x,[y,z])=[(x,y),(x,z)]$ stated at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties), then it is easy:

$(a+b,[a,b])=[(a+b,a),(a+b,b)]=[(b,a),(a,b)]=(a,b)$

where in the second equality I used the easy fact $(x,y)=(x,y \mod x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing $a=d a'$, $b=d b'$, where $d=(a,b)$.

Comment: $l = da'b'$ and $(a',b')=1$.

Comment: Ok. Let d=(a,b), and l=[a,b]. Then d=(a+b,l). But a|l and b|l which means that l=am=bn for some positive integers m,n. Know also that a=da' and b=db' for some positive integers a', and b'. l=da'b' and (a',b')=1. Also ab=ld.

Comment: Let (a+b,l)=gcd(a+b,bn). Then gcd(a+b,bn)|a+b and gcd(a+b,bn)|bn by the definition of gcd. But gcd(a+b,bn)|(a+b)-b by the linear combination property. So, gcd(a+b,bn)|a. Similarly gcd(a+b,bn)|b.So, gcd(a+b,bn)|(a,b) and vice versa. So, (a,b)=(a+b,[a,b]).

Comment: Can anyone evaluate my writing of proof? Thanks!

Comment: @kira: Next time, write it as an addendum to your question; that way, the activity is reflected in the main page. I'll read it shortly and comment.

Comment: @Kira: You go from $\gcd(a+b,bn)|bn$ and $\gcd(a+b,bn)|a+b$ to $\gcd(a+b,bn)|(a+b)-b$. This does not follow from the linear combination property: you know $\gcd(a+b,bn)$ divides any linear combination of $a+b$ and $bn$, but this is a linear combination of $a+b$ and $b$, not $bn$. So you need to justify that assertion somehow, you haven't done so.