# Prove that the sum and product of two positive relatively prime integers are themselves relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Can anyone tell me if my attempt is correct?

gcd (a, a + b) = gcd (b, a + b) = gcd (a, b) = 1.

∴, gcd (a + b, ab) = 1.

Comment: I think it's correct.

Comment: Compare [$\operatorname{gcd}(ab,a+b)=1$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901117/operatornamegcdab-ab-1-if-a-and-b-are-relatively-prime).

Comment: I don't understand how is it that you deduce something about $\operatorname{gcd}(a+b,ab)$ from three statements in which $ab$ does not appear.