# Is $\gcd(x+y, xy)-\gcd(x, y)$ an even or odd number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let's say $d=\gcd(x, y)$

I realize that $d$ is a common divisor of $x+y$ and $xy$, and their greatest common divisor would be some multiple of $d$, let's say $kd$.
So 
$$\gcd(x+y, xy)-\gcd(x, y)=kd-d=d(k-1)$$
so since $d$ can be any value it depends on whether $k-1$ is always even or odd so that it would make the whole thing even/odd.

That's where I get lost. I don't have a lot of experience on this subject so I might be way off. And sorry if the formatting is bad I'm struggling on mobile.

Anyway, thank you in advance.

Comment: Just do it in cases:  If $x,y$ are both even what happens.  If $x$ is even and $y$ is odd what happens (that  may require a contradiction.  What *can't* happen if $y$ is $odd$?) and what happens (or can't happen) if $x$ and $y$ are both odd?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both even.  Then $\gcd(x+y,xy)$ and $\gcd(x,y)$ are both even as well, and the difference of two even numbers is again even.

Now, suppose that at least one of these is odd.  Then one of $x+y$ or $xy$ is odd and it follows that $\gcd(x+y,xy)$ and $\gcd(x,y)$ are both odd as well.  The difference of two odd numbers is even.

As such, $\gcd(x+y,xy)-\gcd(x,y)$ is always even.

Comment: I'm struggling to grasp why two even numbers can't have an odd gcd

Comment: @eks because $2$ is a common divisor to each since they are even and the greatest common divisor is a multiple of every common divisor, so the greatest common divisor must be a multiple of $2$, hence even and not odd.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362975/concise-proof-that-every-common-divisor-divides-gcd-without-bezouts-identity)

Answer (score 2):

It's even: the gcds have equal parity [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901176/242) prime $\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{p\mid x\!+\!y,xy \iff p\mid x,y}^{\textstyle x\!+\!y\equiv 0\equiv xy\iff x\equiv 0\equiv y}\!\!\!\!\!\! $ (here $\,p=2)$.

Comment: Viewed geometrically: $\,xy\equiv 0\,$ (union of both axes) intersects the line $\,y\equiv -x\,$ at the origin. $\ \ $

Comment: In other words $(2|x+y\land 2|xy)\implies 2|-1+(x+1)(y+1)\implies  (2\not |x+1 \land 2\not | y+1)\implies $ $(2|x\land 2|y)\implies (2|x+y \land 2|xy).$

Comment: @Dan $\ xy\equiv 0\,\overset{\rm wlog}\Longrightarrow\, x\equiv 0\,\Longrightarrow\,y\equiv -x\equiv 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on StackExchange.

As you correctly wrote, if $d:=\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)$ and $k:=\frac{\mathrm{gcd}(x+y,xy)}{d} \in \mathbf{N}$, then
$$
S:=\mathrm{gcd}(x+y,xy)-\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)=d(k-1).
$$
At this point, if $d$ is even then clearly $S$ is even. Hence, our question would be: is $S$ *always* even?

To find a counterexample, if it exists, you would need that *both* $d$ and $k-1$ are odd, that is, $d$ odd and $k$ even. Ok, so suppose that $d$ is odd, and make the substitution $x=dX$ and $y=dY$, with $\mathrm{gcd}(X,Y)=1$. It follows that
$$
S=d\left(\mathrm{gcd}(X+Y,dXY)-\mathrm{gcd}(X,Y)\right)=d\left(\mathrm{gcd}(X+Y,dXY)-1\right).
$$ 
Now, what is the value of $\mathrm{gcd}(X+Y,dXY)$? $X$ is coprime with $Y$, hence this is equal to $\mathrm{gcd}(X+Y,d)$, hence a divisor of $d$, which is an odd number. To conclude:
$$
\textstyle S=d\left(\underbrace{\mathrm{gcd}(X+Y,d)}_{\text{odd}}-1\right)
$$
implies that $S$ is always even.

Answer (score 0):

Assume everything relevant is an integer.

$\gcd(even,even) = even$[1]

$\gcd(X, odd) = odd$.[2]

$X\cdot even = even$[3]

$odd \cdot odd = odd$[4]

$odd \pm even = odd$ but  $same \pm same = even$.[5]

Those should get you the answer.

$\gcd(even + even, even*even) - \gcd(even,even) = \gcd(even,even)-\gcd(even,even) = even - even = even$.

$\gcd(even+odd, even*odd) -\gcd(even, odd) = \gcd(odd, even)-\gcd(even,odd)=odd-odd = even$.

$\gcd(odd+odd, odd*odd) - \gcd(odd,odd) = \gcd(even, odd)-\gcd(odd,odd)=odd -odd = even$.

So, yes, $\gcd(x+y, xy) -\gcd(x,y)$ is always even.

........

[1] through [5] are obvious, yes?

[1].  Even numbers are divisible by $2$ so their $\gcd$ will be divisible by $2$.

[2].  Odd numbers do not have $2$ as a prime factor so no common factor with an odd number will have $2$ as a prime factor.

[3].  Every multiple of a multiple of $2$ is a multiple of $2$.

[4]. a) euclids lemma says if $2|x,y$ then $2|x$ or $2|y$ so if $x$ and $y$ are both odd $2|xy$ is impossible.  (Are we could do the elementary way:  $(2k+1)(2j+1) = 2(2kj +k + j) +1$.)

[5].  Hmmm... it'd be fun to come up with the single slimmest line to argue this.  Not sure what the slickest argument is, but some not slick ones are obvious.

$X + even = parity\ of \ X$ because $2|even$ so $2|X+even \iff 2|X$. and $X + odd = opposite \ parity \ of \ X$ because $2\not \mid odd$ so $odd \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 2$ and $X+odd \equiv X\pm 1 \equiv \begin{cases}0+1=1\\1-1=0 \end{cases}$.

But that's the exact *opposite* of slick.

Guess we should go with the inelegant:  $same \pm same = (2j+\begin{cases}0\\1\end{cases}) \pm (2k\mp\begin{cases}0\\1\end{cases})= 2(j\pm k)=even$ whereas $odd \pm even = (2k+1) \pm 2j = 2(k\pm j) + 1 = odd$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the slickest proof, but illustrates the use of $\gcd (a, b)=\gcd(b, b-a)$ which can come in handy in simplifying problems of this type, and is a technique worth noting.

Note that $\gcd(x+y, xy)= \gcd (xy, xy-x-y)=\gcd (xy, (x-1)(y-1)-1)$ and this is clearly odd unless $x$ and $y$ are both even (one of the two numbers is odd).

If both $x$ and $y$ are even, then both gcds are even. Otherwise, both are odd.

If you believe parity is constant as suggested in the question, setting $x=y=1$ solves it for you.