# Prove that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + b, \operatorname{lcm}(a, b))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Is it true that
$$ \gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + b, \operatorname{lcm}(a, b)) $$
for all integers $a$ and $b$?  How to prove it?

For example, take $a = 48$ and $b = 60$.  Now $\gcd(a, b) = 12$, $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b) = 240$, and $a + b = 108$.  Now, the $\gcd(240, 108) = 12$.  Does the relation hold in general for any two integers?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{HCF}$? What makes you think it satisfies this identity? What are some examples of this? What have you tried to prove it? This question needs context. Please see [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about how to ask a good question on this site.

Comment: upvote for curiosity, needs some definitions and examples added to this question. now i am wondering too.

Comment: For clarity, the question is asking whether $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + b, \operatorname{lcm}(a, b))$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: HCF ("highest common factor") is a alternative term for greatest common divisor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + b, \mathrm{lcm}[a,b])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21545/gcda-b-gcda-b-mathrmlcma-b) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%20%5Cgcd(a%20%2B%20b%2C%20%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(a%2C%20b))%24&p=1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @L.F. Yes John Omielan, it was my question. HCF is another name used for GCD.

Comment: FYI, there's also quite a few other duplicates, e.g., [Let $a,b\in \mathbb{N^*}$. Prove that $\gcd(a+b,\operatorname{lcm}[a,b])=\gcd(a,b)$. Is my proof correct?](/q/1854540), [Simpler solution for $\,\gcd(a+b,{\rm lcm}(a,b)) = \gcd(a,b)$](/q/2412544), [Proving or disproving gcd and lcm](/q/3178268), [Prove that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd (a+b, \gcd(a,b))$](/q/2538383), [Derive a simpler expression for $\gcd(a+b,\text{lcm}(a,b))$?](/q/263713), [Relation between $\gcd(a, b)$ and $\gcd(a+b, \operatorname{lcm}(a, b))$](/q/2881027), etc.

Comment: Another interesting property of positive integers $a,b$ is $\gcd(a,b)\cdot $
 lcm$(a,b)=ab.$

Comment: I find it irritating that \gcd is in LaTex but \lcm is not.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
$$

Given $a, b \in \ZZ^*$,
we are trying to show that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + b, \lcm(a, b))$.
(I will ignore the case where $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, in which case whether the statement holds depends on how you define $\gcd(0, n)$.)

Denote $g = \gcd(a, b) \in \ZZ^+$
and let $a = gx$ and $b = gy$
with $x, y \in \ZZ^*$
and $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.
Now $\lcm(a, b) = gxy$, so

$$
\gcd(a + b, \lcm(a, b))
= \gcd(g(x + y), gxy)
= g \cdot \gcd(x + y, xy).
$$

Assume for the sake of contradiction
that $d$ is some prime factor of $\gcd(x + y, xy)$.
Then, $d$ divides $xy$.
Since $\gcd(x, y) = 1$,
$d$ divides exactly one of $x$ and $y$.
But $d$ also divides $x + y$,
so $d$ divides neither or both of $x$ and $y$,
reaching a contradiction.
Therefore, $\gcd(x + y, xy) = 1$,
and
$$
\gcd(a + b, \lcm(a, b)) = g.
$$

Comment: Don’t you need $d$ to be prone to say that $d|xy$ implies that $d|x$ or $d|y$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Indeed - thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the notice.  I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Glad to hear that.